# Windows Threading Options

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++

I would like to evaluate my threading options for a Visual C++ 2010 (non-managed) console application.

Can anybody suggest a good reference for the native Win32 threading API?

What non-native options are recommended?

Thanks!

Best,
Dave

Comment: Did you mean to say 'non-managed' in your last statement?

Comment: Nope, I did mean "non-native". I.e., what non-Microsoft threading libraries are most recommended? It seems that Boost is the clear winner...

Comment: When you speak with most programmers, if you say 'native' they will think native versus managed. This means means the difference between languages and frameworks that manage memory automatically for you versus languages and frameworks where the programmers has to manually manage memory. So your 'non-native' statement really means 'non-microsoft' threading API's.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-native(really these just wrap the native options) options its basically between boost(now part of C++11) and pthreads. For native thread developement you have either WinAPI or CRT threads, thanks to some recent-ish bug fixes, WinAPI is your better option, which is basically `CreateThread`, MSDN has all the documentation you need under the threading and synchronization sections, but I'd recommend using boost/C++11 threads just to make life simpler coding-wise.

Answer (score 4):

You have several choices: Open MP, MPI, Boost, RogueWave.
Or from MS itself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847(v=vs.85).aspx,

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a better reference to get someone started using windows threads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(v=VS.85).aspx

It shows how to use threads using WinAPI, versus just the reference documentation. 
Also if you want the definitive book on how to use C, non-managed threads using C/C++ on windows, then the book: "Windows via C/C++ by Jeffrey Richter", Microsoft Press is the one to read. It is excellent, and gives you so many nuts and bolts of threading, it's just great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with the native Win32 threading facilities, but for C++, Boost's threading library is nice.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned this one:  Intel [Threaded Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/).  If you are trying to write parallel algorithms this one can save a lot of time.  It's a good mature alternative to OpenMP that doesn't rely on pragmas.

Answer (score 0):

Better start off with [Concurrency Runtime in Visual C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Parallel_Programming/parallelcpp.aspx), which utilizes UMS threads in Windows 7, and Windows 2008. It is the the future of concurrency/parallel-programming.